# sending value of my textarea with graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, textarea, mutation

I hope you all have a great day. I am coding my own personal website and I have a section called to contact me. The problem I have with this section is that I am trying to send my client email to my email and when I am trying to send their message to my server through Graphql I get this error

```
[
    {
        "message": "Syntax Error: Unterminated string.",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 3,
                "column": 123
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

the request I sent to my server is

```
'\n        mutation{\n            sendEmail(EmailInput: {name: "Test name", email: "Test@email.com", 
subject: "this is test subject", message: "\n         
   this is the first line \nthis is the second line\nwhen I have multiple lines I have these problem\n
            "}) {\n                success\n                message\n              }\n          }\n        '
```

I don't know how to fix it I don't know why I get this error.
I used fetch to send my code backend :

```
const emailMutationQuery = `
        mutation{
            sendEmail(EmailInput: {name: "${senderName.value}", email: "${senderEmail.value}", subject: "${senderSubject.value}", message: "
            ${senderMessage.value}
            "}) {
                success
                message
              }
          }
          `;

const result = await fetch("http://localhost:2882/graphql", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: emailMutationQuery,
      }),
    });
    const convertedResult = await result.json();
```

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL supports [variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables), which can be used to supply input data separately from the query.  The variables are just a separate JSON-encoded object.  This avoids syntactic difficulties (and potential security risks!) from trying to embed the inputs directly in the query.

For this you'd write a *fixed* query, that declares and uses the variable, but doesn't depend on the per-request inputs

```js
const emailMutationQuery = `
mutation SendEmail($emailInput: SendEmailInput!) {
  sendEmail(EmailInput: $emailInput) {
    success
    message
  }
}
`;
```

You'd then create a second object containing the variable(s).  The top-level keys match what you declare in the GraphQL operation line, and their content matches the corresponding GraphQL input types.

```js
const variables = {
  emailInput: {
    name: senderName.value,
    email: senderEmail.value,
    subject: senderSubject.value,
    message: senderMessage.value
  }
};
```

Note that this is an ordinary Javascript object, and we haven't quoted or escaped anything here.

Now when we make the request, we send the query and variables together

```js
const result = await fetch("http://localhost:2882/graphql", {
  ...,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: emailMutationQuery,
    variables: variables
  })
});
```

Things like newlines in the message content will be escaped in the variables block, and get passed through correctly to the underlying GraphQL engine.

Comment: Thanks, I actually know that but I forgot about it. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find a solution for it but feel free to share your answers here. The solution I found for this problem was that you have to use `JSON.stringify()` for the textarea. you have to pass your textarea value to this function and js will take care of the rest. my code now looks like this

```
const emailMutationQuery = `
    mutation{
        sendEmail(EmailInput: {name: "${senderName.value}", email: "${senderEmail.value}", subject: "${senderSubject.value}", 
        message:${JSON.stringify(senderMessage.value)}}) {
            success
            message
          }
      }
      `;
```

I hope this help you guys.